# access forbidden error when listing caldav directory

Tags: caldav

I am trying to list the users directory of apple calendar server on my localhost. i am getting access forbidden error , its the same for groups as well. my operating system is ubuntu 12.04 LTS. and the package is from the repository.

here is the log of the runshell.py command

```
/calendars/users > ls

        <-------- BEGIN HTTP CONNECTION -------->
Server: localhost

        <-------- BEGIN HTTP REQUEST -------->
PROPFIND /calendars/users/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8008
Authorization: Digest username="test", realm="Test Realm", nonce="17913381079262023151194175611", uri="/calendars/users/", response="df3db481efdc68df9c39733a957f072a", algorithm="md5"
Content-Length: 145
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Depth: 1
Brief: t

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<ns0:propfind xmlns:ns0="DAV:">
  <ns0:prop>
    <ns0:resourcetype />
  </ns0:prop>
</ns0:propfind>

        <-------- BEGIN HTTP RESPONSE -------->
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Date: Mon, 03 Jun 2013 06:48:12 GMT
DAV: 1, access-control
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 139
Server: Twisted/8.2.0 TwistedWeb/8.2.0

<html><head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head><body><h1>Forbidden</h1>You don't have permission to access /calendars/users/.</body></html> 
        <-------- END HTTP RESPONSE -------->

        <-------- END HTTP CONNECTION -------->
Ignoring error: 403
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, have you verified that the request uri that you are using corresponds to the DAV:principal-collection-set property ? See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3744#section-5.8

Then, the principals namespace is typically not queried through PROPFIND but rather through a DAV:principal-property-search REPORT query. See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3744#section-9.4

Now, if you want to retrieve all the users on the calendar server, I'm not sure that the server will actually let you do that, especially if you have a large number of users.